# Questions in tags (e.g. JavaScript) are changing toward libraries and frameworks

Tags: discussion, feature-request

JavaScript is the language in which AngularJS, jQuery, Node.js (uses it), Backbone.js and many other frameworks and libraries have been written. Nevertheless, JavaScript is JavaScript, but most of the time, visiting the new questions in the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag just brings you mostly questions related to third-party libraries and not directly about JavaScript itself.

Don't you think this behavior must be changed, or a new tag (such as [javascript-3rdparty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-3rdparty), [javascript-pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-pure) or [javascript-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-only) (best option here is [javascript-vanilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-vanilla) or [vanilla.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla.js)) should be used to distinguish betwen questions about JavaScript itself and questions about third-party libraries?

Comment: How can you see a list of questions related to javascript itself and not those of third-parties libraries?

Comment: When you are visiting the page with the `javascript` tag, you can see other tags too. If it mentions a library, then you know what it's about. Sometimes such questions can be solved too without having experience with the library itself.

Comment: When you're asking about "JavaScript" itself, are you just talking about what's defined in the ECMAScript specification, or a browser implementation without other user-land libraries?

Comment: Use advanced search to exclude a tag, like [`[javascript] -[jquery]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery)

Comment: This seems to be an increasing problem. Many answers related to JavaScript simply assume that the asker is using jQuery without actually bothering to check.

Comment: Probably not vanilla.js: http://vanilla-js.com/

Answer (score 7):

I can't track it down, but there was a Meta discussion a few years back after a fairly high-rep user created a [c#-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-language) tag that was meant to be for questions *about the C# language itself*, rather than simply about programming with libraries and frameworks that happen to be written in C# or use C# in some way.

It actually seemed like quite a reasonable idea to me, but it was shot down by pretty much everybody who took part in the discussion and the tag was rapidly culled. The overwhelming community consensus - and the pattern of established usage - is that language tags, like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), should be used for both questions about the language itself and for questions about libraries for the language, and that the former - unlike the latter - do not need any additional tags. That does indeed make it near-impossible to find the subset of questions that are specifically about the programming language itself rather than its libraries, but only a tiny minority of users seems to put any value on changing that (and tags such as the ones you're proposing would doubtless be abused and misunderstood anyway).

Comment: You might try your hand at SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/312545

Comment: To be fair, programming languages are rather well-defined things that should leave little mystery to the marginally informed. All answers can be found in books and the official tutorials/wiki for that language.

Comment: The discussion you're referring to is now on Meta.SE: [Congratulations Eric Lippert for finally winning the C#-language badge!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62669), and [John Saunders was the creator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62684/159251) of the tag.

Comment: C# and js are different from this side.

Comment: By the way, [tag:C#-language] seems to be [tag:c#] + [tag:language-design], isn't it?