# Languages vs libraries

Tags: discussion

During the past few years, webdesign has undergone a huge metamorphosis. Where static pages with menus were once a must it is now looked upon as inferior, bad and ugly. Everything must be dynamic. Everything must have effects. Everything must change. Constantly. This reflects itself in the latest developments of the web-languages themselves: HTML became HTML5, CSS became CSS3 and hundreds of JavaScript libraries sprouted out of nowhere, just to accomplish the ongoing changes.

In the meantime Stack Overflow implemented all of these new evolvements as *new tags*. Tags which quite often expand form an expansion on a language, mostly JavaScript. These languages (CoffeeScript, AngularJS, ExtJS, jQuery to name a few) often are not even closely related any more to what they are based on, I accept them as new languages.

As a web developper I know JavaScript, html, php, asp and a few of these new libraries. In NO WAY though it is possible that I and you, my fellow webdesigners, know all of these languages-that-are-not-real-languages. For me, who is proud to engage himself to help people solving webdesign problems, this forms a barrier; I DO follow the tag JavaScript, yet 90% of the posts I get are total JUNK to me. I am not able any more to find the questions I can answer. It is seldom that I find a question about JavaScript in its "humble purity", yet those are the questions I would like to find and I would like to answer if I follow the JavaScript tag. Why? Because if I would like to answer a question about jQuery I would simply follow the jquery tag, if I would like to answer a question about the google maps api, I would follow that tag.

I did read other threads on the meta stackexchange ([this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293878/questions-in-tags-e-g-javascript-are-changing-toward-libraries-and-frameworks) or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276056/how-can-we-differentiate-questions-about-a-language-from-language-libraries)) about the same matter. Yet the answers/solutions provided do not satisfy me. You can indeed search for [JavaScript] without [jQuery]. But am I forced to do that for *every vague library existing*? I don't think that's the way to go. This question also accounts for other languages and their respective libraries of course.

I hence propose a system whereby **tags are sorted into two categories: a language category and category for libraries associated with that language**. If you then follow the JavaScript tag, you should come on an overview/settings page where you can select which libraries you follow, in a tree-like structure and automatically filter the rest. Same for python, c++, c#, java, whatever.

**TLDR;** The JavaScript tag is contaminated with all kinds of posts that in my opinion are not really related any more to JavaScript. This accounts for other languages too and I think it's time for a better approach to this problem.

Comment: I agree that it's hard to find pure JavaScript questions in the [tag:javascript] tag. (It's even harder to find interesting ones that aren't "gimme the codez" or "debug my script for me" questions.) I'm not sure if I agree with your proposed solution, though.

Comment: Is there a reason not to have a "pure-JavaScript" or "vanilla JavaScript" tag?

Comment: @BSMP I doubt many people posting questions would know to use it. You'd probably get a bunch of jQuery questions tagged `jquery` and `vanilla-javascript`.

Comment: You could also add the libraries you don't want to see in your Ignored Tags list. I've done that with a number of the compile-to-js languages like CoffeeScript, and I rarely see them any more.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are crowd-sourced, not curated and not designed. So your suggestion needs to be made to the four winds, as it were.

Comment: If they are crows sourced, why can't they be crowd-sorted?

Comment: Sure, if you can persuade the crowd to sit still and sort.

Comment: Yes, but the multiple categories, the cascading "tree-like" structure and the nightmarish hierarchies to follow would have to be built in.

Comment: If you can persuade people to work away queue's involving minor changes to questions, you can persuade them for tag-sorting aswell I believe.

Comment: @Rsauxil There are currently ~921,000 questions tagged [tag:javascript]. Do you want to be the one to sort through all of them and figure out which are which?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - You wouldn't be sorting the questions, you'd be sorting the tags themselves (though there are still 44,393 tags).