# Subscribe to pure-tags and combo-tags: That makes it easier to find questions you can answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, email

**The feature request**

Many questions relate to a certain mix of tags.

For example a question might be tagged as javascript, jquery. An expert in javascript subscribing to javascript questions is notified of such a question in vain if he knows nothing about jquery. It would be nice if you could subscribe to questions:

> **(1)** Tagged ONLY with a certain tag indicating that is relates purely to
>   e.g. Javascript (`pure-tag`)
>
> **(2)** Tagged with a specific combination of tags representing a 
>   combo-specialization (`combo-tag`)

An example of the `pure-tag` could be: subscribe to questions that is tagged ONLY with `javascript`. An example of the `combo-tag` could be: subscribe to questions that is tagged ONLY with `javascript` & `query`.

**Advantages**

The advantages of such an option would be:

- you could spend *more time drafting good answers* and less time looking for a needle in the haystack
- people specializing in the different pure-tags and different combo-tags could help check that a given question is tagged correctly and thereby help to ensure *overall better categorization of questions*
- better categorization makes it easier for specialized people to find questions within their field of specialization which results in *better answers to the benefit of the people looking for them*

In other words the above will contribute to a positive cycle of increased fun with answering questions and higher quality of the answers provided. And if it gets “to quiet” in a given field of specialization you have subscribed to, you are still free to go visiting “the haystack” to get a feeling of what is going on or to just get new input.

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

I am **not** suggesting to implement *new tags* like for example a `Javascript/Jquery/JSON` - tag. I am suggesting to make it possible to subscribe by e-mail to questions which are tagged with these three separate tags (`combo-tag`). The filter should exclude all questions which does not contain one of these or which contain other tags in addition to these.

Comment: It already works that way, hard to see why it has to be changed.

Comment: @HansPassant: When I try to set up a filter the instructions says: "Any question that matches one of these tags will be displayed in the filter." So that is neither a pure-tag or a combo-tag. This can be confirmed by using the "Preview" button. So: no it does not already work that way.

Comment: Edit your profile, add the tags that you *don't* want to see.

Comment: That of course reduces the "noise". But it does still not result in a pure-tag or a combo-tag as the "favorites" can be combined in any number of ways. Besides it seems a little arcane to have to opt out of tags in stead of just opting in. But thank you none the less for your feedback.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293878/questions-in-tags-e-g-javascript-are-changing-toward-libraries-and-frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Searching for precise combinations of tags is a bad idea. You may be interested in `[a] + [b] + (not [c])`. The problem is many questioners add some other tags that are only vaguely relevant. Look at all the requests here on meta to eliminate unhelpful tags and to make synonyms of others. You may be able to answer their question (and also edit it to remove or correct the irrelevant tags) but doing a search for exactly matching tags would prevent you from finding their question.

Comment: "The problem is many questioners add some other tags that are only vaguely relevant": That is exactly why I think my suggestion is good. First of all it puts greater responsibility on the person asking the question to categorize it correctly, because it else risks to end up in "no mans land". Secondly, if it accidentally ends up in the wrong combo-tag-specilization-field it can be "policed" by the people subscribing to this combo-tag. And lastly: as noted you still can - and I expect many will - go looking in the haystack from time to time and thereby see the "no man's land" questions ....

Comment: And: you can still maintain the existing tag-system. I am just suggesting to add an option for a more specific one.

Comment: I was about to comment the same, better tagging is infinitely more productive than adding another layer of complexity