# Subscribe to multiple tags

Tags: support, tags

How we can subscribe to combination of multiple tags on Stack Overflow?
For example, [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle).

I know how to do this for one tag, but I could not find how to do it for multiple tags.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316708/2675154

Comment: See: [How to subscribe to tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254318/how-to-subscribe-to-tags). It is the same procedure as for one tag: *"Any question that matches one of these tags will be displayed in the filter."*

Comment: This is however wrong, this question is not duplicate. This is not about *one of these* (i.e., tag1 OR tag2), but about *ALL of these* (i.e., tag1 AND tag2). How can I subscribe to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swig+openssl